# What do these Elastic Beanstalk VPC options mean (public IP, subnets for ELB/EC2, and security group)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was setting up an environment using Elastic Beanstalk and I wanted the hosts to be apart of the default VPC for my account. I didn't really understand what the options meant. See the below image for an example:

[image]

1. **Associate Public IP Address** - How does this differ from the ELB visibility?
2. **Subnets for ELB and EC2** - What do these do? The set-up wizard requires at least one box is selected. During my setup I selected all of the boxes.
3. **VPC Security Group** - How does this differ from the security group of the EC2 hosts. I use the security groups to SSH onto the hosts. Why does the VPC need a security group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If selected, the ELB will be created with a public IP address associated to it (or the EC2 instance will if you select single instance instead of load balanced during the setup).  Visibility is just for ACLs, and won't actually give it a publically accessible IP.
2. In a common VPC setup, you'll have both public and private subnets with a NAT in between them. Things in the public subnet can usually access the Internet and private subnet. Private subnet can usually just access the local subnet. In a load balanced EB environment, you'd typically place the ELB in the public subnet and the EC2 instance(s) in the private subnet.
3. VPC security groups are for your resources (anything in your VPC). They're just prefixed with the term VPC so as to distinguish between VPC security groups and legacy EC2 security groups (for EC2 instances that are not part of any VPC). The option in the UI only affects the EC2 resources in your VPC though I believe...not the ELB.

Comment: Regarding the subnets, what do the checkboxes do? There is no public subnet / private subnet option. Only a toggle.

Comment: The checkboxes just indicate what subnet the EC2 instances and ELB will be placed in when AWS spins them up

Comment: In your response you mention public and private subnets. I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what effect these checkboxes have. Could you give an example what would happen if the checkboxes are/are not checked? Also, what is the difference between checking them for ELB/EC2/both? Thanks.

Comment: You need to check at least one for ELB and at least one for EC2 (you can't "not check" them). I believe the UI forces ELB and EC2 subnets to be different but using the CLI or API you can actually have them be the same subnet

Comment: As for public vs private subnets, there is nothing that "makes" a subnet public or private other than the ACLs, routes, NATs, and VPGs (virtual private gateways) that are configured for those subnets in your VPC (see the VPC management console)

Comment: Picture a VPC as your network. You have a DMZ (public) subnet in your network. You have a LAN (private)subnet in your network. You put a load balancer (ELB) in your DMZ and give it a public IP address. You allow the load balancer in your DMZ to access a web server (EC2) (or several) in your LAN. That's what is getting configured here